# Python - Output a list datatype to CNF

Tags: python, list, cnf

I have a list as:

```
KB = [['~p', '~r', 's'], ['~r', 'k'], ['~k', 'm'], ['r'], ['~m'], ['~p', 'r']]
```

I need to output to a file ('output.txt') with CNF format such like this:

```
~p|~r|s
~r|k
~k|m
r
~m
~p|r
```

So what should I do now?

Comment: you should start write the code.

Comment: a little help: `["|".join(x) for x in [['~p', '~r', 's'], ['~r', 'k'], ['~k', 'm'], ['r'], ['~m'], ['~p', 'r']]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BearBrown's comment covers the most important part of the problem. I am adapting to it show how to write to file after joining pipe ('|') as needed.

```
KB = [['~p', '~r', 's'], ['~r', 'k'], ['~k', 'm'], ['r'], ['~m'], ['~p', 'r']]

p = ["|".join(x) for x in KB]

with open('output.txt') as o:
    for item in p:
        o.write('%s\n' % item)
```